# Shiny flexdashboard - plot not rendering

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm building a shiny-based flexdashboard and I'm having a problem rendering

This is my dataframe:

```
structure(list(from_id = c("385588434812408", "385588434812408", 
"385588434812408", "385588434812408", "385588434812408", "385588434812408"
), from_name = c("Стопанска банка - На ваша страна", 
"Стопанска банка - На ваша страна", 
"Стопанска банка - На ваша страна", 
"Стопанска банка - На ваша страна", 
"Стопанска банка - На ваша страна", 
"Стопанска банка - На ваша страна"), 
    year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), month = c(8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), bank = c("stopanska", "stopanska", "stopanska", 
    "stopanska", "stopanska", "stopanska"), likes_count = c(17L, 
    20L, 366L, 240L, 50L, 7L)), .Names = c("from_id", "from_name", 
"year", "month", "bank", "likes_count"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2fae898>)
```

This is my code:

````
Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("bank_id", label = "Select a bank:",
            df$bank, selected = "stopanska")

selectInput('x', 'Year', names(df))
selectInput('y', 'Likes', names(df))
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

dataset <- reactive({
  df[input$bank_id, ]

  })


renderPlot({
  p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_bar()

  print(p)
})

  ```
````

I'm getting the sidebar with the values from the df, but the plot doesn't render. Any hints why?

I'm sure its a very basic question, but I'm new to Shiny.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate the rendering, your code could fall along the below lines. Note that I changed the inputs (`x` and `y`) as the original was not usable in my opinion.

````
---
title: "bank likes"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
df<-read.table(text="from_id                        from_name year month      bank likes_count
385588434812408 Стопанска_банка_На_ваша_страна 2017     8 stopanska          17
385588434812408 Стопанска_банка_На_ваша_страна 2017     8 stopanska          20
385588434812408 Стопанска_банка_На_ваша_страна 2017     8 stopanska         366
385588434812408 Стопанска_банка_На_ваша_страна 2017     8 stopanska         240
385588434812408 Стопанска_банка_На_ваша_страна 2017     8 stopanska          50
385588434812408 Стопанска_банка_На_ваша_страна 2017     8 stopanska           7", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ```{r}
selectInput("bank_id", label = "Select a bank:",
        df$bank, selected = "stopanska")

selectInput('x', 'Year', choices=unique(df$year))
selectInput('y', 'Likes', choices=unique(df$likes_count))
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ```{r}

 dataset <- reactive({
 df[input$bank_id, ]

})


renderPlot({
p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity")

print(p)
})

```
````